# Matrix Function Minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have the following expression for which I wish to find the $\vec{w}$ which minimizes it:

$$
L = \frac{\vec{w}^TA\vec{w}}{\vec{w}^TB\vec{w}} - \lambda(\vec{w}^T\vec{1} - 1)
$$

The partial derivates with respect to $\vec{w}$ and $\lambda$ are as follows

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{w}} &= \frac{2(\vec{w}^TB\vec{w})A\vec{w}-2(\vec{w}^TA\vec{w})B\vec{w}}{(\vec{w}^TB\vec{w})^2} - \lambda \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} &= -\vec{w}^T\vec{1} + 1
\end{align*}

But I'm having a hard time simplifying these to get the minimizing value of $\vec{w}$. Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\w{{\vec w}}$The Rayleigh quotient is invariant to the scaling of $\w,\,$ i.e.
$$\lambda
 = \frac{\w^TA\w}{\w^TB\w}
 = \frac{(2\w)^TA(2\w)}{(2\w)^TB(2\w)}
$$
So there is no point in formulating a Lagrangian to forcibly normalize $\w$.

In fact, the extrema of the Rayleigh quotient correspond to the eigenvalues of
$$\eqalign{
C\w &= \lambda\w \qquad\Longleftarrow\quad C &= B^{-1}A \\
}$$
This eigenvalue problem is also invariant to the scale of $\w,\,$ only the **direction** of the eigenvector is important. Although most numerical libraries will normalize the eigenvectors to have unit Euclidean norm.

Therefore after identifying the minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_{min}\,$ you can take its associated eigenvector and rescale it however you wish, e.g.
$$\w_* = \frac{\w}{{\vec{\tt1}}^T\w}
\quad\implies\quad {\vec{\tt1}}^T{\w_*} = 1
$$

Comment: Thanks @greg, this is actually very interesting - I hadn't heard of the Rayleigh quotient before this. If I wanted to add a non-negativity constraint to the elements of $\vec{w}$, I'm assuming that would only be accomplished via numerical optimization?

Comment: Also, is there any way to find out which $\lambda$ is $\lambda_{min}$ without calculating them all and choosing the minimizer?

Comment: Yes. There are [lots of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms) for solving eigenvalue problems. For minimizations, you want the eigenvalue closest to zero, so set $\mu=0$ in one of the iterative algorithms.